# Where do the Master of Lore and Master of Spells Mage class features come from?

Tags: dnd-4e, class-feature, wizard

Are there any more class features for a Mage beyond what I'm seeing in Heroes of the Fallen Lands?

In there I see:

- School of Magic
- Cantrips
- Magic Missile
- Spellbook

However, I see more listed on this guide:
http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?471408-Archmage-s-Ascension-The-4E-Wizard-s-Handbook-(RuinsFate)

- Master of Lore
- Master of Spells

Did this guy make this up, or is it in another book/magazine somewhere?

Comment: I've changed your title to more closely reflect your question, since the title was causing users to vote to close your question.

Answer (score 3):

The Master of Lore and Master of Spells class features are both found in the Heroes of the Fallen Lands book you mention, at level 21 (page 229) and level 24 (page 233) respectively.